# Sum regex extraction in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, locale, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

In my Google spreadsheet document, I have a table of bills with a column `J` for dates and a column `P` for amounts. I would like to build another table that sums these bills by year (one row = one year). The `P` column has contents like `"3245,20 EUR"`.

Here is the formula I tried (in this example, `S5` should be the sum and `R5` a numeric value of a specific year) :

```
S5=SUMIF(YEAR($J$5:$J), R5, VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT($P$5:$P, "^([0-9]+,[0-9]{2}) EUR$")))
```

This doesn't work. Any solution ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula

```
=SUM(QUERY({A2:A,ArrayFormula(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B,",","."), "^([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}) EUR$")))}, 
             "select Col2 where year(Col1)="&A1&""))
```

The reason we have to use `SUBSTITUTE` is because it looks like the price values come from a different locale.

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`VALUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)
- [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)